# Laravel vue js integration - No values in blade file

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, laravel-elixir

I try to integrate vue.js with laravel 5.3. I call "gulp" which creates the main.js file in the public folder. I can see in the browser that the js file is loaded but the value of "message" is not shown. It is only written {{message}}. Any ideas why?

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="title">                   
                <p>@{{ message }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   <script src="js/main.js"></script> 
</body>
```

gulpfile:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
require('laravel-elixir-browserify-official');
require('laravel-elixir-vueify');

elixir(mix => {
   mix.sass('app.scss').browserify('main.js');
});
```

main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

var app = new Vue({
   el: 'body',
   data: {
      message: 'Hello Vue!'
   }
})
```

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
   "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
   "gulp": "^3.9.1",
   "jquery": "^3.1.0",
   "laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-9",
   "laravel-elixir-browserify-official": "^0.1.3",
   "laravel-elixir-vue-2": "^0.2.0",
   "laravel-elixir-vueify": "^1.0.0",
   "laravel-elixir-webpack-official": "^1.0.2",
   "lodash": "^4.16.2",
   "vue": "^2.0.1",
   "vue-resource": "^1.0.3"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

**package.json**

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "gulp --production",
    "dev": "gulp watch",
    "slate": "rimraf node_modules && npm install",
    "clean": "rimraf public/css/app.css public/css/app.css.map public/js/app.js && npm run dev"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-15",
    "laravel-elixir-browsersync-official": "^1.0.0",
    "laravel-elixir-vue-2": "^0.3.0",
    "laravel-elixir-webpack-official": "^1.0.10",
    "lodash": "^4.17.2",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "vue": "^2.1.6",
    "vue-resource": "^1.0.3",
    "vuex": "^2.1.1"
  }
}
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

require('laravel-elixir-vue-2');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Elixir Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Elixir provides a clean, fluent API for defining some basic Gulp tasks
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for our application, as well as publishing vendor resources.
 |
 */

elixir(mix => {
    mix
        .sass('app.scss')
        .webpack('main.js');
});
```

---

Your code is fine except one thing. Vue JS Doesn't recommend use of body element as vue js root.

> The provided element merely serves as a mounting point. Unlike in Vue
> 1.x, the mounted element will be replaced with Vue-generated DOM in all cases. It is therefore not recommended to mount the root instance to  or

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#el

**Code**

```
<body>
    <div class="container" id="app"> <!-- Mind the id attached -->
        <div class="content">
            <div class="title">                   
                <p>@{{ message }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   <script src="js/main.js"></script> 
</body>
```

and `main.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue';

var app = new Vue({
   el: '#app', // mind the root element is changed to app.
   data: {
      return { // mind the return in data
        message: 'Hello Vue!'
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: I edited like you suggested. But still the same problem. Any other idea?

Comment: See the return statement in data() part of vue

Comment: The return statement nothing changed. Always the same problem. I added the package.json file to my post. Could there be a problem with the used versions?

Comment: Can you open the console of browser and see what is the error..?

Comment: And have you recompiled the js..?

Comment: Yes, and i can See that change in the source code of the Browser. But there is still written {{message}}

Comment: If there is still {{ message }} is written then it only means, vue is not initializing..

Comment: Check if ur script is included, and double check the root element for vue is it there or not..

Comment: yes, the script is included. What do you mean with root element? Now I executed gulp --production. After execution of this command the site is completely blank. But I can see that in the source code of the browser everything is included

Comment: In the console of the browser is written: You are running Vue in development mode.
Make sure to turn on production mode when deploying for production.
See more tips at https://vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html

Comment: @Steve updated gulpfile and package.json file, hope this will solve the issue, and root element is one element per page, where vue keep mounting the virtual DOM. this is a single mounting reference per page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134913/discussion-between-rummykhan-and-steve).